# One line condition not working in data in Vue js

Tags: vue.js, conditional-statements

I have a component that is going to have data named `isVendorOrAgent` that should be `false` or `true` based on a property that the component gets. When I put this condition on the data section of the component, it doesn't work and always returns `false` but when I put that in `created()` and change the `isVendorOrAgent` in `created()`, it works.

How can I make this work?

This is the condition that is not working:

```
data : () => {
   return {
      isVendorOrAgent : (this.entityName == "vendor" || this.entityName == "agent") ? true : false;
   }
}
```

but this works when the default is false:

```
created(){
    if(this.entityName == "vendor" || this.entityName == "agent"){
      this.isVendorOrAgent = true;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Defining `data` as an arrow function is a nono. https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#data https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback

Comment: thank you @EricGuan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code sample:

```
data () {
  return {
    isVendorOrAgent: Boolean(this.entityName === "vendor" || this.entityName === "agent")
  }
}
```

What is different?

1. Now `data` is not an arrow function, because arrow functions do not change the context, so `this` won't be what it should be inside the component
2. We now store a `Boolean` value
3. We are now using strict equality `===`, which is just a good habit

You may also take a look at `computed` properties: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html

Your problem could be solved like this:

```
computed () {
  return {
    isVendorOrAgent: Boolean(this.entityName === "vendor" || this.entityName === "agent")
  }
}
```

The second way is preferable if you need this property to be reactive.

Comment: I think even if it should not be reactive computed is the better way to go. Thanks for the answer i wouldve suggested him the same.

Comment: This is the answer. It must be in computed to be reactive and the misuse of arrow in data hook